# How to install old version (1.8.3) of docker on OS-X?

Tags: macos, docker

There is a nasty bug in Docker 1.9.x that is causing java
processes to hang and frankly hang up the entire container
instance, spinning 100% CPU.

I currently have docker 1.9.1 installed because that is all that
the docker install tool will install.  There is no opportunity during
the install process to select any other version.

This is completely preventing me from building a cordova
build container.  In my internet research I have found many
others who are encountering the same problem.

I've done some research and seen that others are reporting this
problem does not occur with Docker 1.8.3.

I've searched in vain for some hints on how to install older versions
of docker on OS-X.  I tried replacing the boot2docker.iso in ~/.docker/machine/machines/default with the 1.8.3 version downloaded
from here: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/tag/v1.8.3 but that fails miserably.  I am guessing that  there are other things about my default machine (which had been created with 1.9.1) that are incompatible with it.

If anybody has hints as to how I could create a new machine or modify
the existing machine to work with 1.8.3 I would very much appreciate
it.

Alternatively, let me know if there is some other installation method that would allow me to specify which version of docker to install.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that what I needed to do is to find an older version of **DockerToolbox** and that would install the version of docker that I wanted.

I went to the github repository for DockerToolbox:

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases?after=v1.9.

and there I found a link to the 1.8.3 binary:

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/download/v1.8.3/DockerToolbox-1.8.3.pkg

I still had to uninstall my previous installation of docker so I followed the uninstall instructions on this page:

https://medium.com/@itseranga/install-old-version-of-docker-osx-c92ebd5f15f7#.5qh1z0ino

Once I had uninstalled and reinstalled via the legacy DockerToolbox, I managed to build the cordova container:

https://github.com/oren/docker-cordova

without incident.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following:

https://get.docker.com/builds/$(uname -s)/$(uname -m)/docker-.tgz

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1120.

If you happen to know the build number (e.g. 14937) -- not the git commit you see when running docker --version or docker version -- you can form the URL:

```
https://download.docker.com/mac/{{ beta | stable}}/{{ version }}.{{ build number }}/Docker.dmg
# example:
https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/1.12.6.14937/Docker.dmg
```